# Local DNS issue since SMBv1 depreciation

Tags: networking, dns, lan

I have a home LAN with 7 PC's in it all running Windows 10 (5 Home + 2 Pro)

Since last Fall (Autumn) Update some of the PC's fell off the network and were not visible within the File Explorer network tab. My understanding was this was due to the depreciation of SMBv1 which in general is a good thing.

I was not seriously bothered as I was still able to access via the IP address and still share files. I was expecting the issues to be resolved by later updates.

Here we are nearly a year later, and I am still not able to browse my LAN PC's via the File Explorer. I have reset all the PC's individually to permit file sharing but nothing appears in the File Explorer. That is until last month, when out of the blue one PC decided to recognise the LAN, and has started to permit browsing by PC/path name.

I have not changed anything, so I was surprised by this, and expected the remainder to gradually wake up to the LAN. This has not happened, and now the PC that had started to work has stopped again!

I understand the very good reasons to depreciate SMBv1 but it appears that Windows 10 still has not got it's act together with non-domain small LANs.

Can anybody point me to an updated guide on restoring this functionality after the removal of SMBv1.

Many thanks
D.

Comment: SMB v1 is not needed for computers to see and access each other in a non-domain LAN.

Comment: The removal of SMBv1 changed the way in which networked PC's were detected and removed the need for a Master Browser.

Whatever Microsoft have replaced this with is not working